# Displaying the data is sorted from highest value

Tags: mysql

I have a goods price table with some conditions. Here I try to display the quantity of goods that are sorted from the category and price.

**Code snippet:**

```
<?php
    include_once 'db.php';

    $price = 'Price : $10';
    $sql = $DBcon->query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM mytable WHERE article LIKE '%{$price}%' LIMIT 10");

    while ($Row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    $category = "PROMO";
    $Total = $DBcon->query("SELECT title FROM mytable WHERE article LIKE '%{$price}%' AND category='".$category."'");
    $item = $Total->num_rows;

    echo "<li><a href='/tag/". $category ."'>". $category ."</a> (" . $item . " item)</li>";
        }
?>
```

The above code works pretty well for me, but there is one problem.

The actual data on the database are:

- Clothes: 23 items
- Pants: 19 items
- Jacket: 4 items
- Shirts: 11 items
- Bags: 7 items
- and then..

I want to show categories based on the most number of items. But the results of the script code above display randomly. Even the most items just do not appear sometimes.

I know something is wrong with my code, but not sure how to fix it. Please help me.

Comment: [`ORDER BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) was made exactly for that

Comment: I see you are not using aggregate function, I think you should change your query to get count on category and order it by count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are not using aggregate function, I think you should change your query to get count on category and order it by count.

Your code should look something like:

```
<?php
    include_once 'db.php';

    $price = 'Price : $10';
    $sql = $DBcon->query("SELECT category, COUNT(*) as CNT FROM mytable WHERE article LIKE '%{$price}%' GROUP BY category ORDER BY CNT DESC");

    while ($Row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
       $category = $Row["category"];
       $item = $Row["cnt"];

       echo "<li><a href='/tag/". $category ."'>". $category ."</a> (" . $item . " item)</li>";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not great at PHP, but why not query all data at once (assuming not many categories) like so:

```
SELECT category, count(1) as counter FROM mytable WHERE article LIKE '%{$price}%' group by category order by counter
```

If you many categories you can split this by using LIMIT.